# How to add percent status on progressbar fullscreen form interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullscreen

i've use fullscreen form interface from codrops, here is the link [fullscreen form interface](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/30/fullscreen-form-interface/comment-page-4/#comments)

my question is, if want to add percent status on progress bar, what i must do ? here is the part of javascript progressbar :

```
// progress bar
    if( this.options.ctrlProgress ) {
        this.ctrlProgress = createElement( 'div', { cName : 'fs-progress', appendTo : this.ctrls } );
        this._showCtrl( this.ctrlProgress );
    }
```

[image progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqj76.png)

someone have implement? please help

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following links, this may help you:

http://codepen.io/thathurtabit/pen/ymECf 
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

The progress bar can be added with `<progress>;`

Comment: i'm already have a progressbar, myquestion is if i want to add percent number, what i must do